# Raspberry Pi上のUbuntu Serverでログインパスワードをリセットしたい

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi４上でUbuntu Serverを使っているのですが、ログインパスワードを紛失してしまいました。
rootも有効にしていたと思うのですが、rootのパスワードもわかりません。

どのようにパスワードをリセットすればいいのでしょうか?

x64であればGRUBやsystemd-bootのところでシェルを起動するようにすればいいのですが、Raspberry Piではどうすればいいのでしょうか?

ディスク暗号化などは行われていません。

また、GUIはインストールされていません。

Answer (score 0):

私が実際に試した方法ではありませんが、少し調べると以下のような方法があるようです。

---

#### 方法1

RasPi がインストールされた SD カードを別の Linux でマウントし、`/etc/shadow` から該当ユーザーのパスワードを削除してしまう方法があります。
(Windows からだとこの方法は使えないかもしれません)

[How do I reset the lost password of a Pi 4 running Ubuntu server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/137454/95039)

`/etc/shadow` は `:` 区切りで、2列目がパスワードになります。

[「/etc/shadow」ファイル](https://linuc.org/study/knowledge/510/)

#### 方法2

SD カードを別のマシンでマウントし、SD カードの直下にある `cmdline.txt` を編集することでシングルユーザーモードで起動することができるので、この状態でパスワードの再設定 (リセット) を行うことができます。

正常にリセットできた場合には、`cmdline.txt` の内容を元に戻して通常起動に切り替えるのを忘れずに。

[PaspberryPi3のUbuntuでログインパスワードを忘れたときのお話](https://ochanjanai.net/it/301)

> 編集する内容は、末尾に以下のコードを追加します。末尾というか行末？
>
> ```
> rw init=/bin/sh
> ```
>
> (中略)
>
> microSDカードをラズパイに挿して起動します。
> しばらくログが流れますが、ログの流れるのが停止したらEnterキーでも押すとコマンドを入力するプロンプトが表示されます。
> ここで `su` コマンドを実行するとrootになれます。
> あとは `passwd` コマンドでrootのパスワードの変更してください。

Answer (score 0):

(別な方法)
passwd ファイルの編集 の方法
… シャドウパスワード変更するよりは簡単なはず
(試したことはないけれど)

---

手順

1. 当該 microSD カードを別マシンにマウント (別の microSD 起動でも可)
2. パスワード情報を一時的に解除

自動マウントが行われるようなら, マウント位置で
そうでないなら, 以下のような手順で (`mnt/` 以下で) 作業するとよいでしょう

```bash
$ cat /proc/partitions
...
   7       15        276 loop15
   7       16      60408 loop16
   8       16   31166976 sdb
   8       17     218750 sdb1
   8       18   30916975 sdb2

# (自動マウントしてないか確認)
$ mount | grep sdb

$ mkdir mnt
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 mnt
$ cd mnt
$ less etc/passwd
root:x:0:0::/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1::/:/usr/bin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2::/:/usr/bin/nologin
mail:x:8:12::/var/spool/mail:/usr/bin/nologin
ftp:x:14:11::/srv/ftp:/usr/bin/nologin
http:x:33:33::/srv/http:/usr/bin/nologin
...
USER:x:1000:1000:COMMENT:/home/USER:/bin/bash
```

登録したユーザーの UID は 1000 のはず
2項目目の '`x`' はシャドウパスワード使用を意味し, この文字を削除すればパスワードなしに。
(間違って `/etc/passwd` を編集しないように十分注意のこと)

編集は少なくとも `vim.tiny` や `nano` が利用できるはず
編集の後処理

```bash
$ sync
$ cd ..
$ sudo umount mnt
$ rmdir mnt
```

あとは この microSD で起動し, 新しいパスワードを設定するとよいでしょう

参考: [passwd](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/shadow/man1/passwd.1.html)